# Apache CXF Service: How to configure Handler Chain without @HandlerChain annotation?

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, soap-client, cxf-client

I tried following code:

Resolver Class:

```
public class WorkdayHandlerResolver implements HandlerResolver {

    private List<Handler> handlerChain = new ArrayList<Handler>();

    public WorkdayHandlerResolver(){
         this.handlerChain.add( new WorkdayHandler() );
    }

    @Override
    public List<Handler> getHandlerChain(PortInfo portInfo) {
      return this.handlerChain;
    }
}
```

Handler Class:

```
public class WorkdayHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>{
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WorkdayHandler.class.getName());


    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
```

Main Service Class:

```
HumanResourcesService humanResourcesService = new HumanResourcesService();
HumanResourcesPort humanPort = humanResourcesService.getHumanResources();
humanResourcesService.setHandlerResolver(new WorkdayHandlerResolver());
```

When executed the same in server. It does not show any request or response.

Could anyone please help me how to configure handler chain without @Handlerchain annotation as no implementable example or sureshot example i am getting on google?

Answer (score 0):

I removed

```
humanResourcesService.setHandlerResolver(new WorkdayHandlerResolver());
```

and places following line

```
((BindingProvider)humanPort).getBinding().setHandlerChain(Collections.singletonList(new WorkdayHandler()));
```

and it was fixed